# Process.MainWindowTitle changed behaviour in Windows 11

Tags: windows, vb.net, ms-access, process

To be able to use multiple versions of an MS access front-end application I wrote an executable startup utility using vb.net to make a numbered copy (to allow multiple instances: app0.accde, app1.accde etc...) of the front-end and then run it.

It checks all running Access processes using :

```
        Dim AllProcesses() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("MSACCESS")
        Dim mySession As Integer = Process.GetCurrentProcess.SessionId
        Dim MyProcesses As IEnumerable(Of Process) = AllProcesses.Where(Function(pr) pr.SessionId = mySession)  ' filtered
        Dim fileCount As Integer = MyProcesses.Count    ' how much already open
```

and then checks their title text - I appended the file number to the title as I did not find how to retrieve it's file name:

```
        For Each p As Process In MyProcesses
            s = p.MainWindowTitle
            ...
```

and then copy and run an individualised unused copy of the access front-end db using:

```
        If TestAndCopyFile(Appfrom, ProcessName) Then
            Dim Startinfo As New ProcessStartInfo(ProcessName) With {
                    .Arguments = "/cmd " & IniArg,
                    .UseShellExecute = True
                }
            Process.Start(Startinfo)
            ...
```

The problem: that code worked perfectly with windows 10 and versions of MS office from Access 2007 to Access 2021 equally well.
Stopped working under windows 11 as it was returning a null string for MainWindowTitle whatever I tried adding to my code (SetForegroundWindow or ShowWindow API calls).
The "WEIRD" workaround I found was if I minimise and restore the last opened MS Access window by clicking twice it's taskbar icon MainWindowTitle returns the correct window title,  as the program starts as expected even if I open multiple windows between that operation and rerunning that startup utility otherwise the code returns "Could not copy ..." via a catch statement.

I could use that error recovery in a loop until it finds an unused available file name but that's a rough solution.

What does that double clicking of the icon in the taskbar change ?

I suppose I could retrieve the info via a variable assigned to Microsoft.Office.Interopp.Access.Application via the available MainWindowHandle but I did not find how to do it (Assigning as variable to an existing instance of Access.Application using it's Handle).

Comment: I am curious why you need this?

Comment: The application I developped is a bookkeeping + financial assets managment app.
Front end database contains a number of temporary tables and can be connected to different back end databases (different institution or Account for asset managment) via programatical modification of the table links at startup. That allows to open on the same PC multiple versions (windows) of the same Access application (front-end) - by copying it and then running that unique (copy) version - using different configurations (via an .ini file passed as argument to the icon's property).

Comment: I noticed that opening the same Access front-end database more then once in a different context (as needed here) creates conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Although the remark about changed behaviour of process.MainWindowTitle in windows 11 is still valid but while debugging my .NET code It occured to me there was an easier straightforward workaround for detecting the running MS Access copies by just checking for the .laccde files.